# Как выводить значение из JPA (sql запрос) на какой то столбец html таблицы

Tags: java, html, postgresql, jpa

Создал в html таблицу два столбца  и хочу чтобы туда попали данные из JPA (sql) запроса.Хочу чтобы в столбце просрочен вывести условие которая написано в запросе через case when....

```
     DSUtil.java        
     public static List<Question> getQuestions(models.blogs.QuestionStatus questionStatus, models.blogs.QuestionAnswered questionAnswered, Long blogId, Date fromDate, String order, String authorsName, String text, int page, int limit,Date toDate) {
    List<Question> questions = null;
    if (order == null) {
        order = "DESC";
    }

    if (authorsName != null && !authorsName.isEmpty()) {
        questions = JPA.em().createQuery("select q, case when (q.createdDate+interval '15 day')>=current_date then 'da' else 'net' end from Question q where q.removed = false and q.category.removed = false and q.blog.published = true and q.blog.removed = false and UPPER(q.author.fullName) like ?1 order by q.createdDate DESC", Question.class)
                .setParameter(1, "%" + authorsName.toUpperCase() + "%")
                .setFirstResult((page - 1) * limit).setMaxResults(limit)
                .getResultList();
        return questions;
    }

    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
        questions = JPA.em().createQuery("select q , case when (q.createdDate+interval '15 day')>=current_date then 'da' else 'net' end  from Question q where q.removed = false and q.category.removed = false and q.blog.published = true and q.blog.removed = false and UPPER(q.text) like ?1 order by q.createdDate DESC", Question.class)
                .setParameter(1, "%" + text.toUpperCase() + "%")
                .setFirstResult((page - 1) * limit).setMaxResults(limit)
                .getResultList();
        return questions;
    }

    if (fromDate != null) {
        questions = JPA.em().createQuery("select q , case when (q.createdDate+interval '15 day')>=current_date then 'da' else 'net' end from Question q where q.removed = false and q.category.removed = false and " +
                " q.blog.published = true and q.blog.removed = false and " +
                " (date(q.createdDate) >= :createdDate and date(q.createdDate) <= :toDate)" +
                " order by q.createdDate DESC ", Question.class)
                .setFirstResult((page - 1) * limit).setMaxResults(limit)
                .setParameter("createdDate", fromDate)
                .setParameter("toDate", toDate)
                .getResultList();
        return questions;
    }

    list.html
    th class="col-md-1">
                        Просрочен
                        </th>

    <td class="hidden-xs" #{if !question.read} style="font-weight: bold"#{/if}>
                                ${question?.proshroshno}
                                </td>

    models/Question.java
        //TODO
@Column(name = "proshroshno")
public String proshroshno;

    public static Question cloneForwarded(Question question, Blog blog){
    Question clone = new Question();
    clone.text = question.text;
    clone.originalText = question.originalText;
    clone.blog = blog;
    clone.blog.parrentBlog = question.blog;
    clone.category = question.category;
    clone.status = QuestionStatus.APPROVED;
    clone.forwarded = true;
    clone.removed = false;
    clone.createdDate = new Date();
    clone.author = question.author;
    clone.ministerNameEn = blog.nameEn;
    clone.ministerNameKk = blog.nameKk;
    clone.ministerNameRu = blog.nameRu;
    clone.ministerPhoto = question.ministerPhoto;
    clone.published = true;
    clone.read = false;
    clone.ip = question.ip;
    clone.proshroshno=question.proshroshno;
    clone.danniy=question.danniy;
    clone.phone = question.phone;
    clone.parentQuestion = question.id;
    Long counter = countForwarded(question)+1;
    if(question.oldQuestionId!=null){
        clone.number = question.oldQuestionId.toString() + "/"+counter;
    } else {
        clone.number = question.id.toString() + "/"+counter;
    }
    clone.save();
    for (Resource resource: question.getResources()) {
        Logger.info(resource.name);
        Resource newResource = new Resource(new File(resource.getFilePath2()), "url", "mimeType");
        newResource.question = clone;
        newResource.enabled = true;
        newResource.removed = false;
        newResource.createdDate = new Date();
        newResource.save();
        try {
            newResource.copyFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: html страница, это статическая страница. Туда вывести ничего не получиться. Используйте: jsp, thymeleaf, ...

Comment: Я же вывел, и запрос другой у меня  был, только на другую таблицу

Comment: Какой иксепшен выпадает?

Comment: Ошибок нету. Но я не могу понять например как именно на новое поле выводить данные?